# Cosmos DB Increment with Partial Document Update

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, azure-node-sdk

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partial-document-update#supported-operations
says that I can use "increment" to increment a value in my database, however this code

```
const operations =
          [
              { op: 'increment', path: '/public/inventory/irradish', value:  irradish},
              { op: 'increment', path: '/public/inventory/sunmelon', value:  sunmelon},
              { op: 'set', path: '/map/garden/lastUse', value:  time}
          ];
          const { resource: updated } = await container
          .item(
              id = email, 
              partitionKeyValue = email
          )
```

throws this error:

Error: Message: {"Errors":["Invalid value of the patch operation 'op' property in patch request: 'increment'"]}
ActivityId: f1bb8b88-ab68-4f2b-b244-8b021b0d9021,...

How do I increment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use "incr" as answered above.

However regarding the documentation, **`increment`** is just an operation. The samples in the [Node SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/main/sdk/cosmosdb/cosmos/samples-dev/ItemManagement.ts#L208) repository illustrates how to do increment operation,

```
const multipleOperations: PatchOperation[] = [
      {
        op: "add",
        path: "/aka",
        value: "MeFamily",
      },
      {
        op: "replace",
        path: "/lastName",
        value: "Jose",
      },
      {
        op: "remove",
        path: "/parents",
      },
      {
        op: "set",
        path: "/address/zip",
        value: 90211,
      },
      {
        op: "incr",
        path: "/address/zip",
        value: 5,
      },
    ];
    const { resource: patchSource2 } = await container.item(patchId!).patch(multipleOperations);
    if (patchSource2) {
      console.log(`Patched ${JSON.stringify(patchSource)} to new ${JSON.stringify(patchSource2)}.`);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The way to do it is to use "incr" instead of "increment".

I requested the documentation be updated to reflect this.